# Synchronous calls on asynchronous processes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, synchronization

I need to execute a function LoginUser after the RegisterUser function has finished.

The issue is that both functions rely on internal asynchronous calls.

I have tried this, but LoginUser function doesn't seem to wait for RegisterUser  to finish.

Do you know how I can solve this?

```
var registerUser = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {     

        doDometing ...                 

        var registerUserSuccess = function() {
            doDometing ...                             
            resolve("value 1");                                
        };

        var registerUserFailure = function(errors) {
            doDometing ...   
            resolve("value 2");
        };

        externalCall1().then(registerUserSuccess,registerUserFailure);
    }
);


var loginUser = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {     

        // doSomething ...                 

        var loginUserSuccess = function() {
            doDometing ...                             
            resolve("value 3");                                
        };

        var loginUserFailure = function(errors) {
            doDometing ...   
            resolve("value 4");
        };

        externalCall2().then(loginUserSuccess,loginUserFailure);
    }
);

registerUser.then(loginUser);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call loginUser in the "RegisterUserSuccess" function.

RegisterUserSuccess is called when the asynchronous call is finished.

```
var registerUserSuccess = function() {
    // doSomething... 
    loginUser(); // your function call for login user goes here                            
    resolve("value 1");                                
};
```

Comment: Thanks lisa!! That has helped!

Comment: Glad to help. Asynchronous programming with Angular can be a bit confusing at times :)